# Find the Rank value based on the several columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My objective is to find the best code from the dataframe.For an Id No and pdt_No i have to find out the best code using the prob value.So i tried Rank method but it gives overall rank not specific to each Id No.
*Input*

```
Id No Pdt_No code    prob     
 1     pdt1   HHL    0.000000 
 1     pdt3   HHL   50.000000 
 1     pdt2   HHL    0.000000 
 1     pdt5   HHL   50.000000 
 1     pdt8   HHL  100.000000 
 1     pdt1   HHL   50.000000 
 1     pdt2   HHL  100.000000 
 3     pdt1   HHM    0.000000 
 3     pdt1   HHM    0.000000 
 3     pdt1   HHM   25.000000 
 3     pdt4   HHM   33.333333 
 3     pdt3   HHM   33.333333 
 3     pdt2   HHM    0.000000 
 3     pdt2   HHM   50.000000 
 4     pdt5   ERS    0.000000 
 4     pdt2   ERS    0.000000 
 4     pdt2   MKL  100.000000 
 4     pdt2   MKL   50.000000 
 4     pdt5   MKL    5.000000 
 5     pdt1   MKM    0.000000 
 5     pdt1   MKM  100.000000 
 5     pdt1   MKM   33.333333 
 5     pdt1   LPM   63.333333 
 5     pdt2   LPM    0.000000 
 5     pdt2   LPM    0.000000 
 5     pdt2   LPM   33.333333 
 5     pdt2   LPM  100.000000
```

what I have tried is

```
df['rank']=df.groupby(['Id No','Pdt_No'])['prob'].rank(ascending=False)
```

*output*

```
Id No Pdt_No code    prob      rank
 1     pdt1   HHL    0.000000    2
 1     pdt3   HHL   50.000000    1     
 1     pdt2   HHL    0.000000    2
 1     pdt5   HHL   50.000000    1
 1     pdt8   HHL  100.000000    1
 1     pdt1   HHL   50.000000    1
 1     pdt2   HHL  100.000000    1
 3     pdt1   HHM    0.000000    2
 3     pdt1   HHM    0.000000    2
 3     pdt1   HHM   25.000000    1
 3     pdt4   HHM   33.333333    1
 3     pdt3   HHM   33.333333    1
 3     pdt2   HHM    0.000000    2
 3     pdt2   HHM   50.000000    1
 4     pdt5   ERS    0.000000    2
 4     pdt2   ERS    0.000000    3
 4     pdt2   MKL  100.000000    1
 4     pdt2   MKL   50.000000    2
 4     pdt5   MKL    5.000000    1
 5     pdt1   MKM    0.000000    4
 5     pdt1   MKM  100.000000    1
 5     pdt1   MKM   33.333333    3
 5     pdt1   LPM   63.333333    2
 5     pdt2   LPM    0.000000    3
 5     pdt2   LPM    0.000000    3
 5     pdt2   LPM   33.333333    2
 5     pdt2   LPM  100.000000    1
```

Comment: Could you include what your desired output is?

Comment: `max_only = lambda s: s.loc[s['prob'] == s['prob'].max()]`and then `result = df.groupby(['Id No', 'Pdt_No'], as_index=False).apply(max_only)` might be what you are looking for (?)

Comment: @Mrml91 I clearly mentioned that my output i want is rank,This method will give only 1 value

Comment: actually it wasn't as clear as you think it was ("For an Id No and pdt_No i have to find out the best code using the prob value"). Please be more clear on what you expect as output.